# Why autocall probabilities are decreasing with time

Tags: probability, products

I am wondering why autocall probabilities decrease with observation dates. Intuitively, I understand that as time goes, if the spot has not breached the barrier, it would need more and more kind of recovery to autocall. But does anyone has a more rigorous understanding ?

Comment: I am assuming that will depend on what your system displays? It is likely MC simulation? Maybe it is cumulative? If it autocalls with 95% in first period, there will only be 5% left for all other periods in this case.

Comment: It is indeed MC simulation, thank you